# Rails Instance Variable Location

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my website, a user can create a new post from any page. I'm unsure where to put the

```
@var = Model.new
```

though, since it doesn't correspond to a specific controller. What's the best practice for this situation? Would I want to to create it in the application controller? I figure I shouldn't initialize it in the view itself.

Comment: I personally wouldn't mind instantiating it in the view, rather the polluting every controller and every view with a meaningless ivar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would create a `before_filter` in your `ApplicationController` which will initialize `@var` as is necessary.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :initialize_common_components

  # ...

  private
    def initialize_common_components
      @var = Model.new
    end
end
```

Comment: Alright, thanks! Once the 11 minutes pass I'll mark as answer.

Comment: Added a bit of code for how I do this *(using a private method)*

Comment: And you can skip it for some specific controller also. by skip_before_filter :initialize_common_components on that specific controller.